# How to remove any commands that begins with "echo" from history

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, command-history

I have tried the following:

```
history -d $(history | grep "echo.*" |awk '{print $1}')
```

But it is not deleting all the commands from the history with `echo`

I want to delete any commands which start with `echo`, like

```
echo "mamam"
echoaaa
echo "hello"
echooooo
```

Answer (score 2):

You could delete all relevant entries in your `$HISTFILE`, then clear history and (re)load it form the modified file:

```
sed -i '/^echo/d' "$HISTFILE"
history -c
history -r "$HISTFILE"
```

Note that this of course will affect all new shell instances that use `$HISTFILE` to load the old history and thus goes beyond your current shell.

Comment: not working still showing echo commands in history

Comment: @RajarshiDas in the current shell or do you have a parallel one open and running? Also: `^echo` takes commands starting with `echo` only, remove `^` as start-of-line marker if need be.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
history | cut -b8- | grep -v "^echo" > /tmp/TMP; history -c; history -r /tmp/TMP; rm /tmp/TMP
```